# Linking samba shared folders onto FSTAB linux

Tags: mount, fstab, shared-folders

As per the title, I would like to mount automatically the OMV5 samba shared  folders onto FSTAB, however I failed multiple times.

The shared folder is called Rsync_Dell and it is on a static IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer:
Create a folder in mnt; paste this pattern to access to samba shared folder automatically after boots. This command line should be added in /etc/fstab

```
//192.168.XXX.XXX/SourceFolder_name /mnt/TargetFolder_name cifs uid=1000,rw,suid,username=Username,password=Password 0 0
```

- cifs is the type of file system, that is samba share in this case
- UID is your user id, you will get it by running `id` in command line
- SUID is defined as giving temporary permissions to a user to run a program
- rw, stands for reading and writing permissions
- Username and password to access to samba shared folder
- first 0, is for Dumping and Fscking, however I do not have knowledge in it
- second 0, this tells the system which order fsck should perform a file system check